# How to fix the footer so it shows under the sidebar?

Tags: html, css

currently my sidebar is on top of my footer and that's not the place of the footer, I want to place it in the bottom, here's an [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YjgZs.png) that shows what I really want.

```css
footer {
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}

#side {
  width: 19%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  margin: 20px;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div id="side">
    hello
  </div>
</main>
<footer>
  <a href="#">About us</a>
  <a href="#">Contact us</a>
</footer>
```

Comment: Use flexbox on <main> and remove the absolute positioning https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code here will work for you. But i would really recommend you to use CSS Grid & Flexbox instead.

```
main {
    height: 100vh;
}

#side {
    width: 19%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 20px;
    float: right;
    background-color: red;
}
footer {
    padding: 20px;
    margin: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: green;
}
```

These two articles are great to help you learn both:

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/

https://css-tricks.com/css-grid-replace-flexbox/

Comment: thanks a lot @Fadel you are awesome, I added `overflow:hidden;` to fix the overflow. this is the kind of answers I want . you say the solution of the problem and add suggestions to learn, not just tell me go google it or go learn first. THANKS

Comment: This is a fixed sized sidebar, it's not adaptive to if the length of the content you put in the side bar.  Check my answer, it ill adapt to the size of the sidebar.

Answer (score 0):

Here this should work for you and adapt to new content.  You need to wrap it in divs and then allign the divs using float.

HTML

```
<div>
<main>
    <div id="side">
        hello fd sdgsdfgsdg sdfg sdfgfsdg sfdg fsdg sdfg sfdg sdfgsdfgfsd gsdfg
    </div>
</main>
<footer>
<div id="footer">
    <a href="#">About us</a>
    <a href="#">Contact us</a>
    </div>
</footer>
</div>
```

CSS

```
  footer {
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}
#side {
  width: 19%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 20px;
  right:0;
  float: right;
  clear: right;
}

#footer{
  float: center;
  clear: right;
}
```

Comment: thanks John, I just saw your answer. Actually, I deleted the sidebar from my website because I think it's useless now, but if I needed it your answer looks more logical. thanks a lot